# How do I pass username and password in SecuredAuthenticationSoapHeader using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, soap, new-webserviceproxy

I have a SOAP method called AuthenticateUser() that is defined in C# like this

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Returns a token string given a username and password.")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader(nameof(AuthenticationHeader))]
    public AuthenticationResponse AuthenticateUser()
    {
     ...
    }
```

where AuthenticationHeader is type

```
    public SecuredAuthenticationSoapHeader AuthenticationHeader;
```

I'm trying to make a call to this method to get a token so I can use the token to make calls to other methods in the webservice.

When I make this call in SOAP-UI the XML looks like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="https://www.example.com/webservices">
   <soap:Header>
      <web:SecuredAuthenticationSoapHeader>
         <web:UserName>myusername</web:UserName>
         <web:Password>mypassword</web:Password>
      </web:SecuredAuthenticationSoapHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:AuthenticateUser/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However how can I do this in PowerSHell using `Invoke-WebRequest` or `New-WebServiceProxy`?
Is there an alternative way in which I just pass the XML as I do in SOAP-UI?